# como convertir una string con Convert.Todatetime sin el tiempo

Tags: c#, .net

tengo el sig codigo

```
DateTime startMoment = Convert.ToDateTime("01-10-2021");
```

el cual me devuelve el sig valor :

```
01-10-2021 0:00:00
```

como puedo quitar el tiempo

Comment: No se C#, pero si la clase se llama `DateTime`, guarda dia y tiempo. No existe una clase que solo sea `Date`? O algun metodo estilo `getDate` en `DateTime`?

Comment: No, lo que puedes hacer, ¿Para que quieres quitarle el tiempo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

si quieres solo la fecha , sin el tiempo puedes usar [`ToShortDateString`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.toshortdatestring?view=net-5.0), que el resultado te daria `"1/10/2021"`, `dd/MM/YYYY`

```
DateTime startmoment = Convert.ToDateTime("01-10-2021");
var date= startmoment.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Para definir el fomato de una fecha puedes usar el método toString:

```
DateTime startMoment = Convert.ToDateTime("01-10-2021");
startMoment.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy");
```

Donde d : dias, m:meses , y: years (tambiénpodrías incluir segundos minutos horas etc si lo deseas).
Esta es una forma de formatear exactamente como se quiere la fecha en el orden deseado por ejemplo dias antes que meses .